# ListView with multiple clickable things - padding to ignore accidental clicks?

Tags: android, listview, click, onclicklistener

Each of my list items has a Star (styled checkbox) for making the item favourite and the item itself (whole row) can be clicked to open the item.

It works but the issue is slightly clicking off the star causes the click event for main ListItem to fire, I tried to fix this via padding/margin to the Star but clicking that padding area causes a click on the main list item causing the item to be opened when the user missed the tap on the star by a few pixels.

Whats the best way to ignore clicks on the list item say a small margin to the left and completely above and below and to the right of the star ?

(How do I ignore clicks on the red area in the image below?)

[image]

Comment: One solution can be cutting the star images with a little red background,and then place the images in the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of investigation it seems the easiest way to fix this is this:

Add this to the root element of the list item layout:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Add this to the parent of the "Star"/Checkbox, in my case the checkbox lives inside a LinearLayout with some padding on that, so I added this to my LinearLayout:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

This causes the "Clicks" on the LinearLayout around my CheckBox to be swallowed up by it and don't go to  the ListItem OnClick event that the rest of the ListItem responds to.

My whole code for the ListItem layout looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:addStatesFromChildren="false"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:id="@+id/listitem" >


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Item 1"
        />

  </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/favouriteCheckBox"
                android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:visibility="visible"   />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

So far I think padding is the best solution. Give enough padding to your favourite button. But if you say you have already done that, then the other alternative is not to use ListView onItemClickListener and use separate onClickListener for the row items. For example, you can modify your ListView item row layout by giving weights to the child (one to the view which opens item detail and other to the your favourite button) and apply separate onClickListener to both.

Answer (score 0):

Add tag on each view you need to add action on then use   view.gettag()  and switch on tags